# How to get rid of "Send email as you" permission in Appmaker

Tags: google-app-maker

I have an appmaker app that used to send emails. However, my users objected to the permissions required for this feature, so I removed it. However, the "Send email as you" permission is still being requested and I can't seem to get rid of it.

I did the following:

- deleted (not just commented out) all references to MailApp I was able to find via the search bar
- exported my code and searched for Mail just in case I missed anything above
- removed mailto: links, in desperation
- pubished to a new deployment to verify the permissions required

I can see in the deployment that "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail" is being requested, which is undesirable. However, I can't edit it, and I can't see why it's being requested.

No matter what I do, I keep seeing "Send email as you" being requested. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the gmail advanced service turned on?

Comment: It's not listed under "Advanced services" in App Settings

Answer (score 0):

I never solved this problem, but I worked around it by running as developer instead of as user. While doing so, I noticed that I had an old trigger installed. It's possible/likely that old trigger was an email trigger, so perhaps the trigger was what caused the email permission. I'll never know for sure since the trigger was deleted.